# ServerSupportFunction ask DWORD for null-terminated string, how to do on 64 bit?

Tags: c++, delphi, winapi, iis, isapi

I need to call the windows api :

```
BOOL WINAPI * ServerSupportFunction(
  _In_  struct _HTTP_FILTER_CONTEXT *pfc,
  _In_  enum SF_REQ_TYPE sfReq,
  _In_  PVOID pData,
  _In_  DWORD ul1,
  DWORD ul2
);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ff827495(v=vs.85)

That is translated in delphi like:

```
function (
  var pfc{: THTTP_FILTER_CONTEXT};
  sfReq: DWORD; 
  pData: Pointer; 
  ul1, ul2: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall;
```

The winApi doc say that **UL1 (DWORD) must Points to an optional null-terminated string** that contains the headers to add. So I naively try like this (delphi code) :

```
Var LUrl: ansiString;
LUrl := 'Location: https://myserver'+#13#10#13#10
pfc.ServerSupportFunction(
  pfc, // var pfc{: THTTP_FILTER_CONTEXT};
  SF_REQ_SEND_RESPONSE_HEADER, // sfReq: DWORD
  PANSIchar('307 Temporary Redirect'), // pData: Pointer
  Dword(@LUrl[1]), // ul1: DWORD
  0);
```

but this miserably fail with access violation. But as I m on 64 bit, I don't understand how `Dword(@LUrl[1])` will even work as @ return 64 bit address

So how I can do ? Is their a way to force a pointer to stay in 32 bit space so that I can convert it to DWORD ? Or I simply miss something ?

Answer (score 1):

The [doc you linked to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ff827495(v=vs.85)) is wrong about `ul1` and `ul2`. [The main `ServerSupportFunction` doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ff827482(v=vs.85)) that it itself links to shows them as actually being `ULONG_PTR`, not `DWORD`:

```cpp
BOOL WINAPI ServerSupportFunction(
  struct _HTTP_FILTER_CONTEXT pfc, // <- * see note below
  enum SF_REQ_TYPE sfReq,
  PVOID pData,
  ULONG_PTR ul1, // <-- not DWORD!
  ULONG_PTR ul2  // <-- not DWORD!
);
```

<sup>Note: should be `struct _HTTP_FILTER_CONTEXT *pfc` instead.</sup>

Comment: I was just saying that you comment deserve to be an answer when you wrote the answer :) you are very good thank to be here! so do you think I must update the delphi Winapi.Isapi2.pas and rewrite the TFilterServerSupportFunctionProc = function(...ULONG_PTR ) ?

Comment: Yes, the Delphi declaration needs to be updated